# operand size mismatch for movq

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I am trying to generate the byte codes for instruction sequences by using `gcc` and `objdump`.
Here is what I write in file `code.s`:

```
movq $0x1234567891234567,0x602308
```

So what I wanted to do here is putting a long data into an absolute address.

Then I typed in: `gcc -c example.s`

It gave me an error says: `Error: operand size mismatch for`movq'.`

So what is going on here?

Comment: I don t tink that's C code, seems like assembly?

Comment: If the assembler says it doesn't like it, it doesn't like it.  Can you find an example where GCC generates an instruction like that?  If not, you're probably not going to be successful.  If you can, you need to spot what's different about what it does that works compared with what you do that does not work.

Comment: I don't see `mm/m64, imm64` being listed as a supported operand combination for `MOVQ` in Intel's manual. You could load the immediate into one of the 64-bit GPRs (e.g. `rax`) and then write that register to memory.

Comment: @Michael Your solution was particularly effective! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Immediate operands of movq are limited to 32-bit.You need to use movabsq