# Modify RIP register from inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to modify the `rip` register (just for fun). `buffer` should be a memory address, so I do not know why I get `Error: operand type mismatch for 'movq'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(){
        char* buffer;
        buffer = (char*) malloc(8*sizeof(char));
        asm volatile("movq %0, %%rip \n" : : "r" (buffer));
        free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468799/operand-size-mismatch-for-movq.. you can also see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837103/gcc-inline-assembly-error-operand-type-mismatch-for-mov

Comment: @Paulo: those aren't duplicates.  They're attempts to do completely different things that happen to give the same error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In x86 you cannot use `rip` directly as the source or destination of a `mov`. To change `rip` you must `jmp` or `call`, or `ret`.

Try moving your address the `rax` and then `jmp rax`. Make sure you mark `rax` as "clobbered".

The easier way to do what you're attempting though, would be to simply create a function pointer, point it at your allocated memory, and call it.

Note also that your `malloc`ed memory will not be marked executable so your test will crash immediately.  To remedy this, you can use [`mprotect(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) to change the page permissions. This changes them for the entire page, however. The better solution is to use [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to map anonymous, executable pages.

---

First, we write a little assembly function:

**prog.s**

```
[BITS 64]
global addints

;; unsigned long addints(unsigned long x, unsigned int y);
addints:
    mov     rax, rdi    ;; x
    add     rax, rsi    ;; y
    ret
```

Then assemble it, and look at the opcodes:

```
$ nasm -o binary prog.s
$ ndisasm -b64 prog
00000000  4889F8            mov rax,rdi
00000003  4801F0            add rax,rsi
00000006  C3                ret
```

Now code that into our sample program:

**mmap.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE   0x1000  /* always 4 KiB (min.) on x86 */

static const uint8_t mycode[] = {
    0x48, 0x89, 0xF8,   /* mov rax, rdi */
    0x48, 0x01, 0xF0,   /* add rax, rsi */
    0xC3,               /* ret */
};

int main(void)
{
    void *m;

    /* Use mmap to allocate a page of executable memory */
    m = mmap(0, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
             MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    if (m == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed: %m\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    /* Copy our code into the executable memory */
    memcpy(m, mycode, sizeof(mycode));

    /* For safety, remove the 'writable' flag */
    mprotect(m, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC);

    /* Create a function pointer, and point it at the executable memory */
    unsigned long (*func)(unsigned long x, unsigned long y) = m;

    /* Call our code */
    unsigned long result = func(7, 3);

    printf("Result: %lu\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

And give it a whirl:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o mmap mmap.c
$ ./mmap
Result: 10
```

[image: No assembly required!]

Comment: jmp, call, or push / ret.

Comment: _"create a function pointer, point it at your allocated memory..."_ What do you mean exactly? Casting a pointer-to-data to a pointer-to-function is not ISO C.

Comment: @black I'm curious, then, how one would ever implement a JITer in ISO C. This is the exact construct used by the Linux kernel when JITing BPF code.

Comment: It's done by `ld` functions too (like `dlopen`). ISO C doesn't define this, though POSIX-compliant implementations are required to.

Comment: @black I'm not sure why you asked what I meant then, if you already knew :-)